# Nested lists for lines in text file? (Python 3)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm pretty new to coding in python and I'm trying to get my program to read in from a text file and create a list from the lines that looks like so:

```
[['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence'], ['Another', 'sentence', 'to', 'explain', 'what', 'I', 'mean']]
```

That would come a text file like so:

```
This is an example sentence
Another sentence to explain what I mean
```

Basically each new line is a new nested list and each word is a new item.
At the moment I've got this but it doesn't separate the words, despite me using the split function?

```
lines=[]
exampleFile = open('example.txt','rt')
for line in programFile:
    line.split()
    lines.append([line])
print(lines)
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: so you don't want to hear about the mistakes.. JUst you want a simple code .. nice..

Comment: Sorry if the answer I picked offends or something... the other answers where also great and appreciated.. but been as the program I want to create need to be efficient I just picked the most applicable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it in a single line, without any intermediate variables.

```
lines = [line.split() for line in open('example.txt')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
lines=[]
exampleFile = open('example.txt','rt')
for line in exampleFile:
    line = line.split()
    lines.append(line)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the people said above

```
lines.append(line) # you dont need []
```

if you use split function, you only can use it to a string

```
string1 = 'ab'
string2 = 'hello wrold'
```

string1.split() will give you

```
['ab']
```

string2.split() will give you

```
['hello', 'world']
```